# remove only empty folders with empty flag - is it safe

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find

we create the following command in order to remove only the empty folders that older then 100min

```
find /tmp -type  d -empty -mmin +100 -printf '%p was deleted!!\n' -delete
```

because we intend to run it from cron job on production machines

we want to understand if **empty** flag will also ignore folders with links or  empty files

or in other words how empty flag check the folder ?

Comment: Empty means empty. A directory which contains *anything* (symbolic links, other directories, regular files empty or not, device files, sockets, whatever) is not empty.

Comment: @AlexP I would say that's an answer instead of a comment.  If you post that and ping me, I'll come back and upvote...

Comment: Test, test, test

Comment: Test ? what you mean about test? ( it is difficult to cover all cases )

Comment: @yael I see you asking about safety and running code in production. Have a Test system and create test cases and & etc. No one here can test your environment like you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empty means empty. If there is any sort of file in a directory, then the directory isn't empty. To illustrate:

```
$ mkdir dir{1..8}; \
  ln -s /etc/ dir1/workingLink; \
  ln -s noSuchFile dir2/brokenLink;  \
  mkfifo dir3/fifo; 
  touch dir4/emptyFile; \
  echo foo > dir5/nonEmptyFile; \
  touch dir6/.hiddenFile; \
  mkdir dir7/subdir
$ tree -a
.
├── dir1
│   └── workingLink -> /etc/
├── dir2
│   └── brokenLink -> noSuchFile
├── dir3
│   └── fifo
├── dir4
│   └── emptyFile
├── dir5
│   └── nonEmptyFile
├── dir6
│   └── .hiddenFile
├── dir7
│   └── subdir
└── dir8
```

So, we have a directory with a working symlink, one with a broken link (pointing to a non-existant file), one with a FiFo (a named pipe), one with an empty file, one with a file that isn't empty, one with a hidden file, one with a subdirectory and only one that's empty. Which one will be deleted?

```
$ find . -type d -empty -printf '%p WAS DELETED!\n' -delete \
                        -or -printf '%p: not empty!\n'
./dir8 WAS DELETED!
./dir3/fifo: not empty!
./dir3: not empty!
./dir5/nonEmptyFile: not empty!
./dir5: not empty!
./dir6/.hiddenFile: not empty!
./dir6: not empty!
./dir2/brokenLink: not empty!
./dir2: not empty!
./dir4/emptyFile: not empty!
./dir4: not empty!
./dir7/subdir WAS DELETED!
./dir7 WAS DELETED!
./dir1/workingLink: not empty!
./dir1: not empty!
.: not empty!
```

So, three things were deleted:

1. The empty directory `dir8`.
2. The empty (sub) directory `dir7/subdir`
3. The (now) empty directory `dir7`. This was deleted because `find` first deleted `dir7/subdir` and then `dir7` was empty so that was deleted as well.

So, any type of content in a directory will stop it from being deleted by this command, but you need to be careful in case the only thing in a directory is other, empty, directories. In that case, the `find` command will also delete the parent directory since it will be empty by the time it finishes.

If you don't want to remove subdirectories which might cause a parent to be removed, with GNU find (the default on Linux) you can use the `-maxdepth` flag to limit `find` to only the current directory:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -printf '%p WAS DELETED!\n' \
                                    -delete -or -printf '%p: not empty!\n'
./dir8 WAS DELETED!
./dir3: not empty!
./dir5: not empty!
./dir6: not empty!
./dir2: not empty!
./dir4: not empty!
./dir7: not empty!
./dir1: not empty!
.: not empty!
```